# How to add serial number in Excel while printing

Tags: microsoft-excel, printing

I am printing 6 payment slips in 1 A4 paper from excel, all 6 slips has same information like Name, payment date and etc... while there is a cell called Serial number. I want to print serial number in each 6 cells of the same A4 paper.

For example on cells C4, C 10, C14 and C18 I want serial number while i print it should show.

I will print 100 A4 paper at once which means I should have at least 600 serial numbers.

Please help.

Comment: Have you considered making a table or list of each item and generate the serial number there? You can then reference the serial number in the other table from your standardized payment slip format using VLOOKUP if you have unique data.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a formula like

`=row()`

in each of the cells. That will print the row number. Assuming the slips are all in different rows, that will give you a unique number for each slip.